# How to set User-Defined Variables in h2 database?

Tags: java, h2

I am trying to set a user defined variable with a H2 database in Java.

When I set a variable with a `NULL` value, it works fine. But when I try to define a variable with `0` as the initial value, I get this error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
>
> Syntax error in SQL statement "`SET @ROWNUM[*]=0;` "; expected "identifier";

SQL statement:

```
SET @rowNum=0; [42001-171]
```

My code:

```
SET @rowNum=0;       // gives error
SET @townroute=NULL; // works fine
```

How can I set an integer value to a variable?

Comment: I have also tried this: SET @rowNum='0'; But not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ROWNUM`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#rownum) is a built-in function, you can't assign a value to it. You will need to use another name, for example `ROW_NUM`.

Comment: Can you do one more favor for me? Can I use 'if' condition with these variables. My code is : @row_Num=IF(t.townroute!=@townroute,1,@row_Num+1) AS townsr

Comment: it gives error : org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "IF" not found; SQL statement:

Comment: Is here 'CASE WHEN ' is suitable or not? How can I use it?

Comment: See [the documentation of CASE WHEN](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#case_when)